# Mapping two json with jq and script bash

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a json file *list_values.json* with array of json with an "origine" field :

```
[
        {
          "origine": "reason1",
          "identifiant": "1234_AAA"
        },
        {
          "origine": "reason3",
          "identifiant": "5678_BBB"
        }
]
```

I have *mapping.json* file with a list of predefined fields :

```
{
  "REASON_0": "reason0",
  "REASON_1": "reason1",
  "REASON_2": "reason2",
  "REASON_3": "reason3",
  "REASON_4": "reason4"
}
```

I wrote a bash script using jq with this line :

`jq '.[] |= . + {"type": (.identifiant | split("_") | .[1] )}' list_values.json > add_fields.json`

My file *add_fields.json* :

```
[
        {
          "origine": "reason1",
          "identifiant": "1234_AAA",
          "type": "AAA"
        },
        {
          "origine": "reason3",
          "identifiant": "5678_BBB",
          "type": "BBB"
        }
]
```

I would like to add a "reason" field equal to the key of *mapping.json* whose value matches the "origine" field of *list_values.json*. Like this :

```
[
        {
          "origine": "reason1",
          "identifiant": "1234_AAA",
          "type": "AAA",
          "reason": "REASON_1"
        },
        {
          "origine": "reason3",
          "identifiant": "5678_BBB",
          "type": "BBB",
          "reason": "REASON_3"
        }
]
```

What can I do this with jq ?

I specify that the values of *mapping.json* are unique as the keys.

Comment: Your mapping goes the wrong way. Are you asking how to reverse the keys and values or do you need more detailed help?

Comment: Yes, is it possible for you to create the mapping file in the opposite direction (keys and values swapped)? That would make it a bit easier to get your result

Comment: If you don't want to accept either of the answers you received, please post an answer of your own and accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following looks understandable and extensible: it first builds a lookup object (with `INDEX`) and then maps each input object to a new object with the added properties:

```
jq 'INDEX(input|to_entries[]; .value) as $mapping
| map(
  .type=(.identifiant/"_"|last)
  | .reason=$mapping[.origine].key
)' list_values.json mapping.json
```

Alternatively, merge an object with the new properties into the existing items of the array:

```
jq 'INDEX(input|to_entries[]; .value) as $mapping
| .[]
|= . + {
  type: (.identifiant / "_" | last),
  reason: $mapping[.origine].key
}' list_values.json mapping.json
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "origine": "reason1",
    "identifiant": "1234_AAA",
    "type": "AAA",
    "reason": "REASON_1"
  },
  {
    "origine": "reason3",
    "identifiant": "5678_BBB",
    "type": "BBB",
    "reason": "REASON_3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

With jq 1.6+ you can use `JOIN` to get the matchings. To this end, you need to flip keys and values for the index (in the mappings object). In doing so, you can already insert the `"reason"` field name, which makes it easier to just `add` the results afterwards:

```bash
jq '[JOIN(
  input | with_entries({key: .value, value: {reason: .key}});
  .[] | .type = (.identifiant | split("_")[1]);
  .origine;
  add
)]' list_values.json mapping.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "origine": "reason1",
    "identifiant": "1234_AAA",
    "type": "AAA",
    "reason": "REASON_1"
  },
  {
    "origine": "reason3",
    "identifiant": "5678_BBB",
    "type": "BBB",
    "reason": "REASON_3"
  }
]
```